# Saffari border radius overflow issue

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a situation like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uqhwt1wj/

HTML:

```
<div class="activity_rounded">
    <img class="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/059cOzT.png?1" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.activity_rounded{
    width: 165px;
    height: 165px;
    border-radius: 165px;
    -moz-border-radius: 165px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background: #FFDE15;
}

.image{
    max-width: 226px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;    
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

It works all good in all browsers, however in safari it seems like `overflow: hidden` ignores border radius of the block and hides overflow only for full div block(square). Tried to Google around, but haven't seen any solutions with horizontal centering that would work properly in my case.

Any suggestions, links or comments would help a lot.

Comment: border-radius doesn't need to be prefixed.

Comment: border-radius is issue in safari. Check. http://www.tonylea.com/2010/safari-overflow-hidden-problem/

Comment: @ketan: That is very much a different issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this case cross-browser solution that I decided to use was: using image as background image of a div instead of wrapping image element inside a div.

So now code looks like this([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uqhwt1wj/5/)):

HTML:

```
<div class="activity_rounded"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.activity_rounded{
    width: 165px;
    height: 165px;
    border-radius: 165px;
    -moz-border-radius: 165px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/059cOzT.png?1') no-repeat center #FFDE15;
}
```

Hope this helps to anyone as well.